# How to count near circular objects in image

Tags: image-processing

I have a image similar to below. In that I need to find all red circles and count them.
So, I am thinking to use MATLAB R2011a with Image Processing Toolkit for it. How could I possibly extract them?

[image]

Comment: Please give us lots more detail.  Will there be any other red objects visible in the image?  Will the red objects always be approximately the same size (in pixels), or might they vary?  Do you need to deal with occlusion (e.g., a tomato that is partly occluded by a leaf in front of it)?  I hope you're aware that many of the tomatoes in your image are not in fact red circles, because they're occluded by other objects (e.g., leaves, other tomatoes): what were you hoping should happen in that case?

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach to start with is to extract just the red channel, do some binary thresholding (e.g., Otsu's method), and then use standard [morphology operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology) to find the blobs. You could try applying a closing operation.  Then, you could apply the watershed transformation or region flooding to identify the blobs where the tomatoes are.

A possibly better approach could be to convert to HSV representation, then generate a binary image as follows: every pixel whose hue matches the hue of a tomato (from some range you manually determine) is colored white, the rest are colored black.  Then you could continue with morphology operators and watershed/region flooding.

How well this will work will depend upon your requirements (e.g., whether you need to deal with occlusion) and on application-specific details (e.g., how constant in color the tomatoes are).

Take a look at the following questions on StackOverflow; they are quite relevant and will be helpful to you:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/11631188/781723
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/4063965/781723
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/5298884/781723
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/4387488/781723
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/10480609/781723
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/6416117/781723
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/10313602/781723
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/18972932/781723
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/10168686/781723
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/8593091/781723
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/16100708/781723

and also these resources:

- http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/06/02/cell-segmentation/
- http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/examples.html?file=%2Fproducts%2Fdemos%2Fshipping%2Fimages%2Fipexcell.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_detection

Answer (score 0):

For finding all the circles, all you need is to use a feature extraction technique which I recommend SIFT. SIFT is easy and ready to use in [VLFeat](http://www.vlfeat.org/) library.

Since SIFT is made for gray-scale images, a possible problem may be color. I suggest using it on a gray-scale image. In case it was not able to distinguish a red circle from a green one, you can think of CSIFT [[1]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1640995) which is an "A SIFT Descriptor with Color Invariant Characteristics".

An easier way is to employ a histogram of colors besides the SIFT to have the color description of each patch it extracts.

In case you needed a detailed explanation for each part, leave a comment below.

Hope I could help.